# how to filter array with date range?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
array = [#<Product id: 206, product: "first product", created_at: "2018-05-28 09:50:26", updated_at: "2018-05-28 09:50:26">, #<Product id: 207, product: "second product" ,created_at: "2018-05-28 09:50:46", updated_at: "2018-05-28 09:50:46"]

params[:from_date] = "2018-04-28 09:50:26"

params[:to_date] = "2018-05-28 09:50:46"
```

I'm filtering the above array with the following params `(params[:from_date], params[:to_date])`  using the below `select` statement.

```
array.select { |product| product.created_at >= params[:from_date] && product.created_at <= params[:to_date] }
```

I think there are more efficient methods than the above.

Are there any other methods to tackle this issue in a more efficient way?

Comment: I think it's perfect

Comment: `(params[:from_date]..params[:to_date]).cover? product.created_at`

Comment: @mudasobwa its working fine, how cover? is different from include?

Comment: [`Range#include?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Range.html#method-i-include-3F)  performs additional checks for whether the range is integer (click on “view source”.)

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought of improving the SQL query? It looks like your array contains the `Products` that are result from a query like `Product.all`. Maybe you can change that to something like:

```
Product.where("created_at >= :from_date AND created_at <= :to_date",
  {from_date: params[:from_date], to_date: params[:to_date]})
```

I think that is more efficient approach because you will improve your app performance. And from my point of view the code looks more understandable this way.

Comment: can't do that, because `product` is not coming from `Product.all`, It's coming from `@page_instance.users.includes(:products).map(&:products),
end result will be array anyway

Comment: then you can instead of doing an include, change it for a join like this
@page_instance.users.joins(:products).where(...) and do the filter there. if you really need the complete array first and then filter, the solution that you have at the moment is the one to go.